# Is 176.34.131.233 really Duckduckgo.com address?

Tags: dns

I would like to identify the ip owner. Can someone help me with that?

PS 
I reside in Moscow, Russia.

Comment: nslookup gives me `ec2-176-34-131-233.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Are you not able to perform an nslookup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ nslookup DuckDuckGo.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Server:  dns.tb.iss.as9143.net
Address:  212.54.40.25

Name:    DuckDuckGo.com
Addresses:  176.34.131.233
          46.51.197.88
          176.34.135.167
          46.51.197.89
```

Whois Results:

```
176.34.131.233 is ec2-176-34-131-233.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
46.51.197.88 is is ec2-46-51-197-88.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
176.34.135.167 is ec2-176-34-135-167.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
46.51.197.89 is ec2-46-51-197-89.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

From https://duck.co/help/company/architecture

> We both run our own servers and have servers on Amazon EC2 across the world. Your connection generally goes to the closest regional server available to your area.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Its AMAZON] Its not the Duckduckgo.com, by the way its AMAZON's address

Comment: If it is Amazons IP, why do I land on DuckDuckGo if I go to `http://176.34.131.233` with my Browser?

Comment: Because DuckDuckGo.com is a domain that is running on an IP that is part of the block owned by Amazon.

Comment: Except the website isn't owned by amazon but likely uses amazon's services in some way